# How to write fixed width text file with PHP and MYSQL data

Tags: php, text

I have an issue in writing fixed width text file using php and data from mysql db. Pl find below format where I have a customer table:
customer name of 100 char width 
customer address of 200 chars width.

### I need to print these in the below format.

```
3M India Limited                         Plot 48-51 Electronic City
Biocon Ltd                               20th KM Hosur Road,Electronic city
```

Now my customer name keeps varying, but I need to fix this width and then print Address. Below is my code where I am manually giving the spaces which is causing the data to go haphazard when written in a text file.

php Code:

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "    ".$cust2[Ac_desc];
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "                                        ".$cust2[Add1]."\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you decide a static width for your first column, say 100 characters.

Then try with this code

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "    ".$cust2[Ac_desc];
$spaces = 100 - strlen($cust2[Ac_desc]); // get the number of spaces to add
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = str_repeat(" ",$spaces).$cust2[Add1]."\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: event this works, but there is a easier way what AlienWebguy has suggested, thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure your `Ac_desc` and `Add1` are defined constants or quote them to treat as associative indexes.

Second, try the [str_pad()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) function.

```
fwrite($fh, str_pad($cust2['Ac_desc'], 100));
fwrite($fh, str_pad($cust2['Add1'], 200));
```

Comment: Hi AlienWebguy, I tried your lines, it is working only for the first line, i am unable to add a line break and add 2 more values, pl check the code below if there is any issue:
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

fwrite($fh, str_pad($cust2['Ac_desc'], 100));
fwrite($fh, str_pad($cust2['Add1'], 200));

$stringData = "\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);

fwrite($fh, str_pad($dtl2['Prod_desc'], 100));
fwrite($fh, str_pad($dtl2['Rate'], 200));
fclose($fh);

ob_end_flush();
mysql_close($link);

Comment: @Shikiryu that reflects his PHP example, but not his desired formatting example.

Comment: @user1114409 depending on your machine you may need `\r\n` instead of just `\n`

Comment: @AlienWebguy now it is working fine, this is the best answer which worked cool, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL's [`RPAD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_rpad) function together with its [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html) command:

```
SELECT
  RPAD(ColumnA, @width, ' '),
  RPAD(ColumnB, @width, ' '),
  -- etc.
INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/file.prn'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY ''
LINES  TERMINATED BY '\n' STARTING BY ''
```