# PHP creating text file with dynamic data from MYSQL issue

Tags: php, text

I am writing a Text file with php using mysql db fields, which are dynamic in nature. I am unable to keep the column width intact, pl see the below data and columns to get a better idea of what I mean.

Text file output:

```
                450 65445 90900 87954          112
              90900 45875 24565 15484          KA01 23232
```

php script for the above:

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

if ($quer2[DCNO1]>0){fwrite($fh, str_pad($quer2[DCNO1],19, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT));} if ($quer2[DCNO2]>0) {fwrite($fh, str_pad($quer2[DCNO2],6, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT));} if ($quer2[DCNO3]>0) {fwrite($fh, str_pad($quer2[DCNO3],6, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT));} if ($quer2[DCNO4]>0) {fwrite($fh, str_pad($quer2[DCNO4],6, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT));} 
fwrite($fh, str_pad($dchd2['PO_No'],13, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT));
$stringData = "\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);

if ($quer2[DCNO5]>0) {fwrite($fh, str_pad($quer2[DCNO5],19, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT));} if ($quer2[DCNO6]>0) {fwrite($fh, str_pad($quer2[DCNO6],6, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT));} if ($quer2[DCNO7]>0) {fwrite($fh, str_pad($quer2[DCNO7],6, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT));} if ($quer2[DCNO8]>0) {fwrite($fh, str_pad($quer2[DCNO8],6, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT));}
fwrite($fh, str_pad($dchd2['Vehicle_no'],20, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT));
$stringData = "\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);

fclose($fh);
```

Now if one value in the column is 0 then the space gets removed because of my IF condition, in such a situation, how do i calculate the space and give those extra spaces.

text file output if one of the values are 0 in my IF condition:

```
                450 90900           112
              90900 45875 24565 15484          KA01 23232
```

Comment: [try this][1]<br>str_pad("", 20); also works fine but try the link also


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460298/how-to-write-fixed-width-text-file-with-php-and-mysql-data?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tab stops ("\t"). It ensures each item on different lines start on the same columns.

It means that when item is 2 chars long and can't fill the 4 space tab, 2 whitespaces are added.

Bear in mind: different editors have different notions for tabs, some typically insert spaces instead of tabs.

*Edit:* Actually more simple solution will be to have an else clause and write str_pad("", 20);

Comment: Well, you still have the same problem, just in multiples of 8.

Comment: Yep you're right, he's just not using it consistently in every code execution path, hence the problems.

Comment: @LukaRamishvili the else option is a better option. it works fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: @LukaRamishvili, this solution was for horizontal spacing, but if I have vertical line space reqd, probably I should give \n based on number of line printed already, right ?

Comment: @user1114409 sorry for the late reply. Actually, for laying out tabular data, \n wouldn't be useful, because with tabs, you can still manage columns in the subsequent rows. Newlines, in the contrary, won't give you a chance to position multiple items on one line. You have to either rotate the generated table (first column set as first row, etc) or do a custom for loop where you manually manage line feeds and tabulation to get a rotated table. I hope I understood what you wanted to do.

Comment: @user1114409 If you simply want to divide each line by, say, 2 empty lines, then don't base it on the number of lines already printed, but just echo "\n\n" each time a line ends.

Comment: e.g. `line 1 item 1 item 2 item 3 \n\n line 2 item 1 item 2 \n\n line 3.. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is VERY busy,  try centralizing it all through a function where you can handle the '0' in one place.  Something like the below (this code has not been tested,  but should give you the right idea.

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

function writepad($str,$pad)
{
    global $fh;
    if($str==0) $str=" "; //handle the case where str is 0, replace it with a space
    fwrite($fh,str_pad($str,$pad,STR_PAD_LEFT));
}
writepad($quer2[DCNO1],19);
writepad($quer2[DCNO2],6);
writepad($quer2[DCNO3],6);
writepad($quer2[DCNO4],6);
writepad($quer2['PO_No'],13); 

fwrite($fh, "\n");

writepad($quer2[DCNO5],19);
writepad($quer2[DCNO6],6);
writepad($quer2[DCNO7],6);
writepad($quer2[DCNO8],6);
writepad($quer2['Vehicle_no'],20); 

fwrite($fh, "\n");

fclose($fh);
```